# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 23): O O O O O O O

Tags: knowledge, visual, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](/q/124796/) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124826/)</sub>

---

Evening all! Please put the images in chronological order:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

THIS PUZZLE IS ABOUT THE:

> **O ANTIPHONS** (ALSO KNOWN AS THE GREAT O'S)

> BEST KNOWN FROM THE HYMN **O COME O COME EMMANUEL** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Antiphons)

WHICH ARE:

> ONE OF THE KEY MUSICAL FEATURES OF THE DAYS LEADING UP TO CHRISTMAS UP UNTIL **23RD DECEMBER** (WHICH IS WHY THE PUZZLE HAS BEEN POSTED TODAY)

PUTTING THE IMAGES IN ORDER IN THE RELEVANT SEQUENCE:

> 1) = O SAPIENTIA (**O WISDOM**) = IMAGE OF NORMAN WISDOM = 17TH DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Wisdom)

> 2) = **O ADONAI** = IMAGE OF ADONAI MITCHELL = 18TH DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adonai_Mitchell)

> 3) = O RADIX JESSE (**O ROOT OF JESSE**) = IMAGE OF SQUARE ROOT OF JESSE PINKMAN = 19TH DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Pinkman)

> 4) = O CLAVIS DAVID (**O KEY OF DAVID**) = IMAGE OF DAVID STRAZ KEY OF CITY = 20TH DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Tampa_mayoral_election#Candidates)

> 5) = O ORIENS (**O DAWN OF EAST**) = IMAGE OF DAWN OF EAST MOVIE) = 21ST DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_of_the_East)

> 6) = O REX GENTIUM (**O KING OF NATIONS**) = IMAGE OF MARTIN LUTHER KING = 22ND DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King_Jr.)

> 7) = **O EMMANUEL** = IMAGE OF EMMANUEL MACRON = 23RD DECEMBER (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmanuel_Macron)

THIS:

> EXPLAINS THE TITLE - **O O O O O O O** !

Comment: All correct. I'd just note that there is a little significance to the location of the third picture.

Comment: STOP SHOUTING! But seriously, use sentence case, not all caps. And is that (gur Havgrq Angvbaf urnqdhnegref)?

Comment: i'll capitalise when i want to.. THANKS